# Showing students records based on classifications in two different tree views

Tags: python, odoo, view

I am working on students module.According to requirement one super user of application have all rights to access it , where as another user(teacher) only view the all students based on classification e.g Students of o level
how i can do this ?

```xml
<record id="student_view_form_status" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Status</field>
    <field name="model">student.registration</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="10" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Status">
            <field name="registered_date" />
            <field name="status" />
            <field name="student_name" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="patient_visits_action_form_status_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Status</field>
    <field name="res_model">student.registration</field>
    <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="student_view_form_status" />
</record>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you short answer. Use DOMAIN.

Fore more details read official Odoo [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/).

Comment: It's very trivial, but if you cant solve it after reading documentation I can give you odoo source link for example codes

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you want specific users to only see entries (students) of a defined level. Let me take that a bit more abstract: an entry has 2 or more (x, y, ...) states and user a (superuser) can see all entries while user b (teacher) can only see entries of state x.

In Odoo you will need user groups (`res.groups`), access rights (`ir.model.access`) and access rules (`ir.rule`) to get this requirement done.

You will find a very good example in Odoo's `sale` module. There are 3 user groups in that module: See own leads, See all leads and Manager. A sales order (`sale.order`) can be read by all sales users (access right for all users is read, create and write).
But there are also access rules defined. The sales order have a field called `user_id`, which in context of sale is the salesman of the order. The rules are defined that the users of group "See own leads" can only see orders where they are or nobody is the salesman. The next "higher" group "see all leads" is overruling this constraint by its own access rule, which grants read access to all sales orders.

You can use the same implementation for your requirement. For more information look into the `sale` module and ofcourse into the [Doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html)